# Utilize the same user for both MC Connect integration and admin/dev activities

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

Our client has run out of Salesforce licenses and he's asking us to install the MC Connector in order to integrate their marketing cloud instance with their org.

So we only have one user to utilize for both MC integration (the famous MC connect user who you assign permissions to in order for the integration) and current/future developments on the Sales cloud org.

Could this have any particular impact on performances/functionality of Salesforce?

I might be asking a stupid question, but I guess there's a reason why Salesforce makes you create a separate user for the MC integration.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Translation of Jonas' answer below: yes, it's possible but it's A Very Bad Idea (tm).

Comment: that is a very succinct way to put it!

Answer (score 3):

This is not the full answer - generally, there are things that I would be cautious of, like risking too many open sessions which could invalidate the one for the connector, but I have never been able to fully get behind it.

If YOUR account (as an implementation partner) is to be used, then there is a hard gotcha:

- You have to ensure your password never expires so the connector stays up.
- And if your client (god forbid) decides to change partners, they essentially cannot disable your account or the connector goes down. All they can do is change your password, and this *also* impacts the connector, to the point where they might have to reinstall it (or revert the password change). I have some war stories in my notes that changing the MC connect user's credential should be avoided, and I've made the experience twice that someone tried, unsuccessfully.